# How to change language runtime for fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using `navigation component` for Single Activity architecture. I'm trying to change language of my app in runtime, I'm using this [article](https://medium.com/ironsource-tech-blog/conversion-by-translation-changing-your-android-app-language-at-runtime-5c9daebf9771) to do so.

So I've the following files:

**RuntimeLocaleChanger**

```kotlin
object RuntimeLocaleChanger {

    fun wrapContext(context: Context): Context {

        val savedLocale = Locale(PreferencesHelper.readLanguageCode()) // load the user language from SharedPreferences

        // as part of creating a new context that contains the new locale we also need to override the default locale.
        Locale.setDefault(savedLocale)

        // create new configuration with the saved locale
        val newConfig = Configuration()
        newConfig.setLocale(savedLocale)

        return context.createConfigurationContext(newConfig)
    }

    fun overrideLocale(context: Context) {

        val savedLocale = Locale(PreferencesHelper.readLanguageCode()) // load the user language from SharedPreferences

        // as part of creating a new context that contains the new locale we also need to override the default locale.
        Locale.setDefault(savedLocale)

        // create new configuration with the saved locale
        val newConfig = Configuration()
        newConfig.setLocale(savedLocale)

        // override the locale on the given context (Activity, Fragment, etc...)
        context.createConfigurationContext(newConfig)

        // override the locale on the application context
        if (context != context.applicationContext) {
            context.applicationContext.run { createConfigurationContext(newConfig) }
        }
    }
}
```

**Application**

```kotlin
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(RuntimeLocaleChanger.wrapContext(base))
}
```

**MainActivity**

```kotlin
override fun attachBaseContext(base: Context) {
    super.attachBaseContext(RuntimeLocaleChanger.wrapContext(base))
}

override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    RuntimeLocaleChanger.overrideLocale(this)
}
```

I change the language like this:

```kotlin
// PreferencesHelper.readLanguageCode() is the language code saved in SharedPreferences
if(PreferencesHelper.readLanguageCode() == "en") {
    PreferencesHelper.writeLanguageCode("he")
} else {
    PreferencesHelper.writeLanguageCode("en")
}
```

I feel like there is something missing but I can't get my head to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution:

**MainActivity**:

```kotlin
override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    // Will give the direction of the layout depending of the Locale you've just set
    window.decorView.layoutDirection = Locale.getDefault().layoutDirection
}
```

**Fragment**

```kotlin
// PreferencesHelper.readLanguageCode() is the language code saved in SharedPreferences
if(PreferencesHelper.readLanguageCode() == "en") {
    PreferencesHelper.writeLanguageCode("he")
} else {
    PreferencesHelper.writeLanguageCode("en")
}
(activity as? MainActivity)?.recreate()
```

I've also found a nice library [locale-helper](https://github.com/zeugma-solutions/locale-helper-android)